# Add Gradle task dependency only if task is invoked by another task

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add two "setup" and "cleanup" tasks that should be executed at the beginning and at the end of the build only if the build is invoked via a certain task.

In the following example, the `setupTask` and `cleanupTask` should only be executed, at the beginning and at the end of the build, if and only if the build was launched by the `releaseX` task.

The line marked with `(1)` makes the `releaseX` task depend on the corresponding `assembleX` task, so that a standard Android build is produced.

The line marked with `(2)` is the key line that should make `setupTask` to be invoked at the beginning of the build. This is the line for which I'm asking for help, because `setupTask` is always invoked, and not only when launching the build via `releaseX` as I would like.

The line marked with `(3)` performs the cleanup jobs at the end of the build.

Can you help me?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
        //...
    }
    signingConfigs {
        //...
    }
    productFlavors {
        //...
    }
    buildTypes {
        //...
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0]
        def releaseTask = tasks.create(name: "release" + flavor.name.capitalize(), type: Copy) << {
            //...
        }
        releaseTask.dependsOn variant.assemble     // (1)
        variant.preBuild.dependsOn setupTask       // (2)
        releaseTask.finalizedBy cleanupTask        // (3)
    }
}

task setupTask << {
    // ...
}

task cleanupTask << {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify, that releaseTask.dependsOn setupTask and that variant.preBuild.mustRunAfter setupTask.

The mustRunAfter specifies an ordering but not a dependency.

I did not try that, it may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the following, albeit much less elegant than Henry's answer.

The dependency of `preBuild` on `setupTask` is always declared, but `setupTask` is disabled if the task graph doesn't contain a `releaseX` task.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0]
        def releaseTask = tasks.create(name: "release" + flavor.name.capitalize(), type: Copy) << {
            //...
        }
        releaseTask.dependsOn variant.assemble
        variant.preBuild.dependsOn setupTask
        releaseTask.finalizedBy cleanupTask

        gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
            if (!(taskGraph.allTasks.any { it.name.startsWith("release") })) {
                setupTask.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```